# OpenVPN connection works in CLI but not in GUI (via NetworkManager)

Tags: debian, networkmanager, openvpn, gnome3

Using Debian 11.

I set up CyberGhost VPN using the `.ovpn` file, client key and certificates they provide on their website. Copied all files to `/etc/openvpn/`. Using the following commands will allow me to connect in the terminal:

```
cd /etc/openvpn

sudo openvpn --config openvpn.ovpn
```

For some reason to connect successfully I have to be in the `/etc/openvpn` directory or else it will say that the key and certificates are not found.

When I try connecting through the GUI (the GNOME NetworkManager) in the settings, the connection fails immediately.

Running `sudo systemctl status NetworkManager` gives the following errors:

```
Jul 26 13:02:55 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[5657]: UID set to nm-openvpn
Jul 26 13:02:55 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[5657]: Initialization Sequence Completed
Jul 26 13:02:55 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[5657]: event_wait : Interrupted system call (code=4)
Jul 26 13:02:55 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[5657]: net_addr_v4_del: 10.10.4.64 dev tun0
Jul 26 13:02:55 debian-desktop NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1690369375.0903] vpn-connection[0x55acfc3d84f0,a278295b-7548-4b85-872a-437b96a2cc46,"CyberGhost",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: started (4)
Jul 26 13:02:55 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[5657]: sitnl_send: rtnl: generic error (-1): Operation not permitted
Jul 26 13:02:55 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[5657]: Linux can't del IP from iface tun0
Jul 26 13:02:55 debian-desktop NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1690369375.0905] vpn-connection[0x55acfc3d84f0,a278295b-7548-4b85-872a-437b96a2cc46,"CyberGhost",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Jul 26 13:02:55 debian-desktop NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1690369375.0905] vpn-connection[0x55acfc3d84f0,a278295b-7548-4b85-872a-437b96a2cc46,"CyberGhost",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Jul 26 13:02:55 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[5657]: SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
```

`sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` gives more insight:

```
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1690371016.4656] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="a278295b-7548-4b85-872a-437b96a2cc46" name="CyberGhost" pid=1975 uid=1000 result="success"
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1690371016.4681] vpn-connection[0x55acfc3d8700,a278295b-7548-4b85-872a-437b96a2cc46,"CyberGhost",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 6190
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1690371016.4720] vpn-connection[0x55acfc3d8700,a278295b-7548-4b85-872a-437b96a2cc46,"CyberGhost",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1690371016.4979] vpn-connection[0x55acfc3d8700,a278295b-7548-4b85-872a-437b96a2cc46,"CyberGhost",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1690371016.4979] vpn-connection[0x55acfc3d8700,a278295b-7548-4b85-872a-437b96a2cc46,"CyberGhost",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-256-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). Future OpenVPN version will ignore --cipher for cipher negotiations. Add 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers or change --cipher 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers-fallback 'AES-256-CBC' to silence this warning.
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: WARNING: file '/etc/openvpn/client.key' is group or others accessible
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: OpenVPN 2.5.1 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on May 14 2021
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022, LZO 2.10
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]37.46.115.44:443
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: UDP link local: (not bound)
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: UDP link remote: [AF_INET]37.46.115.44:443
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: NOTE: chroot will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: WARNING: 'link-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='link-mtu 1569', remote='link-mtu 1553'
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: WARNING: 'keysize' is used inconsistently, local='keysize 256', remote='keysize 128'
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: [belgrade-rack403.nodes.gen4.ninja] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]37.46.115.44:443
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: sitnl_send: rtnl: generic error (-101): Network is unreachable
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openvpn-service-openvpn-helper --debug 0 6190 --bus-name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn.Connection_6 --tun -- tun0 1500 1552 10.3.4.78 255.255.255.0 init
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1690371016.8377] manager: (tun0): new Tun device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/7)
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop systemd-udevd[6202]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1690371016.8417] vpn-connection[0x55acfc3d8700,a278295b-7548-4b85-872a-437b96a2cc46,"CyberGhost",0]: VPN connection: (IP Config Get) reply received.
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1690371016.8422] vpn-connection[0x55acfc3d8700,a278295b-7548-4b85-872a-437b96a2cc46,"CyberGhost",7:(tun0)]: VPN connection: (IP4 Config Get) reply received
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1690371016.8425] vpn-connection[0x55acfc3d8700,a278295b-7548-4b85-872a-437b96a2cc46,"CyberGhost",7:(tun0)]: VPN connection: (IP6 Config Get) reply received
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop NetworkManager[851]: <warn>  [1690371016.8425] vpn-connection[0x55acfc3d8700,a278295b-7548-4b85-872a-437b96a2cc46,"CyberGhost",7:(tun0)]: invalid IP6 config received!
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop NetworkManager[851]: <warn>  [1690371016.8426] vpn-connection[0x55acfc3d8700,a278295b-7548-4b85-872a-437b96a2cc46,"CyberGhost",7:(tun0)]: VPN connection: did not receive valid IP config information
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: chroot to '/var/lib/openvpn/chroot' and cd to '/' succeeded
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: GID set to nm-openvpn
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: UID set to nm-openvpn
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: Initialization Sequence Completed
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1690371016.8438] vpn-connection[0x55acfc3d8700,a278295b-7548-4b85-872a-437b96a2cc46,"CyberGhost",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: started (4)
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: event_wait : Interrupted system call (code=4)
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: net_addr_v4_del: 10.3.4.78 dev tun0
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: sitnl_send: rtnl: generic error (-1): Operation not permitted
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: Linux can't del IP from iface tun0
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1690371016.8460] vpn-connection[0x55acfc3d8700,a278295b-7548-4b85-872a-437b96a2cc46,"CyberGhost",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop NetworkManager[851]: <info>  [1690371016.8461] vpn-connection[0x55acfc3d8700,a278295b-7548-4b85-872a-437b96a2cc46,"CyberGhost",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop gnome-shell[1975]: Removing a network device that was not added
Jul 26 13:30:16 debian-desktop nm-openvpn[6196]: SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
```

I believe this is where the critical error occurs:

```
invalid IP6 config received!
VPN connection: did not receive valid IP config information
```

The error seem to be in the IPv6 configuration, but I'm not really sure why. CyberGhost recommends turning off IPv6 completely and running `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6` returns `1` which means IPv6 is disabled. Enabling IPv6 results in the same issue.

I imported the connection in GUI from the `.ovpn` file.

Packages are up to date.

EDIT: IPv6 is disabled on the system and in the VPN configuration (CyberGhost suggests to disable it). All other settings are default.

## UPDATE

So, to any poor souls who have spent hours trying to fix this, like I did - here's a solution! The problem lies in the fact that the `network-manager-openvpn` for Debian 11 has a bug regarding IPv6. To solve this we will install the newer version from the unstable branch. To do so, follow these steps:

Add the following lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free
deb-src https://deb.debian.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free
```

Next, create this file: `/etc/apt/preferences.d/99debian-unstable`, add the following text to it:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 50
```

This is added to prevent the system from pulling all packages from unstable, and only install the ones you specify. Packages from unstable, especially mix-matched with packages from stable, can be detrimental to the stability of the system, and installing them is never recommended, however this is the only solution.

Run `sudo apt update`. If your system was up to date prior to adding the unstable branch, and this command says that there are packages to upgrade, DO NOT UPGRADE. If this happens that means you didn't set the preferences correctly, and if you upgrade your entire stable system to the unstable branch you will end up breaking it.

If everything seems OK, run the following command:

```
sudo apt install -t unstable network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

Then run `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`

You should be good to go!